# Laravel 5.5 . How can I validate date using laravel validator

Tags: php, laravel

I have some fields which defines passport_issued_date and passport_expiration_date. I need to check activity of given passport by comparing with current time. I would do it by using native php, however I would like to know if there is some way to make a validation using laravel 5.5 validation  on dates.

Comment: might be you need this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-date-format please also put your code here not the question that needs the descriptional answer

Comment: i had just update a answer

Answer (score 5):

Try this way,

```
$current_time=\Carbon\Carbon::now();

$validator = Validator::make($request_data, [
    'passport_issued_date' => ['date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',"after_or_equal:$current_time"]        
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 422);
}
```

Comment: The field under validation must match the given format. You should use **either** date or  date_format when validating a field, **not both**. - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-date-format

Comment: I need to compare two dates.

Comment: i had update my answer. if you want match to with current date then specify after:yesterday in validation rule.

Answer (score 2):

See this rules https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date or https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date-format
and all available rules https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules

```
Validator::make($request_data, [
    'start_date' => 'date',
    'end_date' => 'date|after_or_equal:start_date',
]);
```

or

```
Validator::make($request_data, [
    'start_date' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'end_date' =>'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s||after_or_equal:start_date',
]);
```

and after it

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 422);
}
```